Code working in Jupyter notebook but not working in IDLE
I am tying to do conditional formatting through color code using below code. This works fine with jupyter notebook but is not working in IDLE python 3.7 (64).
`
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd
  from IPython.display import display
  df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,3))
  ap=df.style.map(lambda x: 'background-color : yellow' if x>df.iloc[0,0] else '')
  display(ap)

I was expecting that the code will work in both jupyter & IDLE.

You aren't understanding several things. Python running in IDLE and Jupyter which runs in your browser and uses a Python-backed kernel are two very different things. If you open a terminal in Jupyter and put python on the line. What comes up will be more in line with 'Python running in IDLE'. Jupyter with a Python kernel has all sorts of conveniences and features that Python running in IDLE doesn't. Like displaying styles Pandas dataframes. It is spelled out in the Pandas documentation that it is meant for Jupyter, see here.

To help in context. Python was there to run in IDLE and terminals and consoles many, many years ago. Then Fernando Perez improved Python with IPython which added several conveniences and features still in terminals and consoles. Then IPython Notebook extended IPython to be in a browser-based framework adding additional features and conveniences. Finally, Project Jupyter took IPython Notebook idea and added other language kernels and expanded the conveniences and features even further. You can though do what you want perhaps in different ways. Maybe. See ...

 here, here, or here for different aspects of abilities in Jupyter vs Python in a terminal/text-based context.

When asking questions about something not working, please give a detailed description of the errors you get. Here, it is not clear from your question what does not work.

When asking questions about something not working, please give a detailed description of the errors you get. Here, it is not clear from your question what does not work

When you use libraries like IPython.display.display, the output includes HTML for styling, which is supported in Jupyter Notebooks. However, standard Python environments like IDLE do not have built-in support for rendering HTML or CSS. I hope that brought clarity to your question.
